# Using Mutliple Selection Dropdown with ASP

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

I'm fairly new and not very good at ASP, so please bear with me.

In my HTML form I have a multiple selection dropdown, like the one below:

```
 <span><select id="movieMonster" name="movieMonster" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="">Please select all that apply</option>
      <option value="The Mummy">The Mummy</option>
      <option value="Dracula" selected>Dracula</option>
      <option value="The Wolfman">The Wolfman</option>
      <option value="The Gillman" selected>The Gillman</option>
      <option value="The Wasp Woman">The Wasp Woman</option>
 </select></span>
```

I have looked everywhere and tried everything to get the items selected transfered over to my ASP file when the submit button is pressed.  However, only one of the values transfers over.

I am using the following in my ASP:

```
 Mnstr = Trim(Upload.Form("movieMonster"))
```

The closest thing I could find was some code that will display all items selected, but the code has to be used on the same HTML page as the form.  It works great, except that I cannot get the data to transfer over to my ASP.

The code I found is the following:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <style>
      div { color:red; }
 </style>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

      <select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
           <option>Flowers</option>
           <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
           <option>Trees</option>
           <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
           <option>Grass</option>
           <option>Dirt</option>
      </select>

      <div></div>

      <script>
           $("select").change(function () {
                var str = "";
                $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                     str += $(this).text() + " ";              
                });
           $("div").text(str);
           })        
           .trigger('change');
      </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The `<div></div>` in the above is what prints the selected items.
I have rigged the code to work for me and changed the use of div to another variable, because I needed to, and that has worked.  It will print every item selected from the multiple selection drop down, but I can't get that information over to the ASP file.

Since I couldn't get the info over to the ASP, I also tried using a hidden input, but that has not worked either.

If anyone knows of an easy way to do what I need, I would be really grateful.

I'm sure there has to be a simple way to do this, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the upload component. See: [Upload.Form returns only the first selected item of a multi-select control](http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS01032617) .

As the workaround suggests, you will have to loop through the form fields named `movieMonster` in your asp page.

Your asp code should be something like :

```vbs
Mnstr = ""
For Each Item in Upload.Form
  If Item.Name = "movieMonster" Then 
    Mnstr = Mnstr & Item.Value &","
  End If
Next 

'remove the extra comma if there is one
if (trim(Mnstr)<>"") then
    Mnstr = Left(Mnstr,len(Mnstr)-1)
end if
```

Comment: @ SearchAndResQ.  I tried using the code from the above link and I'm still getting only one item from the list.  Before using this code I got the first item, now it's the last.  I did have to adjust the code, since I did not want to write out the items on the list, I wanted them to become the value of a new variable.  I feel like I need to add some code that will allow the concatenation of all the selected items in the multiple selection drop down.  I wanted to post my modified code here, but can't seem to get that to display properly.

Comment: @ SearchAndResQ.  Thanks for saving my life!  Not to mention my sanity.  This worked beautifully.  A very big Thank You.